# Driver for Audio Device on High Definition for Lenovo R61i

Tags: firefox

Recently my Laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad R61i) was formatted but i have failed to get the sound back. I have failed to access the driver for the Äudio Device on High Definition on Audio Bus. I was told that it is them one responsible for letting out the sound.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Intel Chipset updat package and install that.  Have you installed and used [Lenovo Systm Update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE) app.  That can really help with problem drivers/devices.